# Option of Sending parameters to stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I have a stored procedure that accepts 10 parameters. I want to send some of these parameters when executing another stored procedure. How can I do that?

Stored procedure definition:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_name] 
    @p1 int = null,
    @p2 int = null
    ..
    ..
    @p10 int = null
```

Execute statement :

```
exec SP_name  valueForP2,vlaueForP5..;
```

Are there any why to tell exec statement to take just some of the variables?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the parameter names in the call to the procedure, the other parameters will use the default values.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_name] 
    @p1 int = null,
    @p2 int = NULL,
    @p10 int = NULL
AS 
    SELECT @p1, @p2, @p10

GO

-- Execute using named parameters
EXEC    [SP_name] @p1 = 1, @p10 = 5;
```